# How can I troubleshoot a range hood light failure?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, hood

The Allure by NuTone stove hood in my house went dark - after flickering for a while, the light bulbs stopped turning on.

I did what anyone would do, and placed new light bulbs in the sockets - unfortunately, nothing happened. So I'm assuming the problem is electrical / wire-related and has nothing to do with the light bulbs.

Are there troubleshooting steps I could run to make sure the problem is electrical and not the light bulbs?

It is almost impossible to get an electrician in my area right now. How difficult would it be for someone without knowledge to fix or replace the wiring or bulb sockets in this stove hood?

[image: Range hood control panel]

[image: Bottom of hood showing light bulbs]

Comment: Although I don’t fully agree with @jack below and upvoted with the power off I would check the center conductor on the light sockets. Edison or screw in sockets do sometimes get loose and lifting or prying the center away from the bottom of the socket may just fix it. Look at the bottom of the old lamp is it nice and clean or pitted and burned, a common problem in the old days of incandescent lamps of high wattage.

Comment: "Easily" is a subjective thing and off topic here. I've revised your title to something more specific and objective. Feel free to revise further, but see [ask] for tips.

Answer (score 7):

The fact that the lights were flickering before totally going out would lead me to believe there's a loose connection at the switch or that the switch is bad. You can check different appliance parts stores online for diagrams of your hood. You'll need the model number. You can access a diagram similar to the one below for your hood.
[image]

You'd have to remove cover #21 and screw #20 to get to the light sockets and wiring and also to the switches. From there, you would need a multi-meter to perform continuity checks on the wiring and switch for the lights. This could be difficult with no knowledge of appliance repair. You would need to learn how to use multi-meter and make sure all power is turned off to the stove top and hood before doing **any** work or investigating. Since you're unfamiliar with this type of work, a handyman or appliance repair person with electrical knowledge might be your best bet.

Comment: I give a up vote for everything but flickering could be caused by a loose connection, this was quite common in lamps with the base above the lamp, my most recent flicker problem was with some new lamps I purchased for my wife, one of them would flicker every now and then I thought it was the LED bulbs swapped out and a few days later it was totally dead. Turned out the conductor was loose I took it apart tightened things up and it has never flickered again. + for providing a breakdown and turning power off.

Comment: @Ed Beal are you saying that a loose connection could not cause flickering?

Comment: Oops I just re read it I thought you said it could not be loose, sorry I did up vote and made the comment about loose connections at the lamp and screw.

Comment: Additionally, while things are open, look for any wiring that looks burnt or charred. This would be a first clue that there _are_ loose connections - they could cause arcing, which would cause the burned/charred appearance. If there are screw connected wires, ensure the wires are well seated and tighten the screws. If they are push-on spade type connectors, ensure the connectors are pushed fully together and that the crimps holding the wire to the connector are not loose. Loose connectors are easy to repair, but that's a whole new question (that may have already been answered).